# Undesirably autologging-in after reboot - do not even have nopasswprd group

Tags: permissions, login, shutdown

After normal full shutdown and reboot I am automatically logged in.

If I logout, then the password prompt will appear.

If I logout, and then shutdown, and then reboot, autologin again occurs.

Running groups:

```
% groups
userme adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

No "nopassword" group.

This is a brand new behavior after 5 months of normally appearing login prompt after reboot.

Any clue what it could be?

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable Ubuntu auto-login, you can follow the below steps, and in step 5. **Toggle the Automatic Login switch to OFF**.

Ubuntu auto-login is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html):

> **Log in automatically**
>
> You can change your settings so that you are automatically logged in
>   to your account when you start up your computer:
>
> 1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.
> 2. Click Users to open the panel.
> 3. Select the user account that you want to log in to automatically at startup.
> 4. Press Unlock and enter your password.
> 5. Toggle the Automatic Login switch to ON.
>
> When you next start up your computer, you will be logged in
>   automatically. If you have this option enabled, you will not need to
>   type in your password to log in to your account which means that if
>   someone else starts up your computer, they will be able to access your
>   account and your personal data including your files and browser
>   history.

More info provided by the OP @Craig Hicks:

> - The actual file which is changed is `/etc/lightdm.conf` .
> - A line is added: `autologin-user=<username>`.

Comment: Yes it can be controlled from that menu.  The actual file which is changed is /etc/lightdm.conf .  A line is added: "autologin-user=<username>".  I tried removing that line first before seeing your answer and it worked.  Still a mystery as to how that setting for autologin got turned on.  I'm wonderung if maybe something I did caused lightdm to become activated whereas it wasn't before.

Comment: @CraigHicks - happy to know that the problem was solved! added the info from your comment into my answer. Thanks! :)